# Alinear una label y texto en tabla con angular material

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap

Buenos dias Comunidad,

Me encuentro maquetando un proyecto personal web , me gustaria pregunta una duda que me surgido desarollando una tabla con angular material y bostrap en Angular.

Se trata de que no consigo alinear el texto del Parámetro con los labels para que quede a la misma altura y alineado.

Muchísimas Gracias por ajuda Comunidad.

Adjunto imagen y código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<table matSort class="table table-lg mt-3 main-table big-cells" aria-describedby="mydesc">
            <thead class="col-lg-6">
              <tr>
                <th class="table-margin"></th>
                <th mat-sort-header="name" class="table-firmware-name">Parametros</th>
                <th mat-sort-header="version" class="table-small-col">Umbral de Proteccion</th>
                <th mat-sort-header="device_model" class="table-medium-col">Tiempo de Actuacion</th>
                <th class="table-margin"></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody class="section-list pb-lg-3 mb-lg-5 mx-lg-3">
                <tr  class="generic-card px-lg-4 py-lg-3 mb-lg-2">
                  <td></td>
                  <td class="row-left-border table-firmware-name">SobreTension - Fase 1</td>
                  <td class="row-middle">
                    <p class="input input-password mb-1">
                      <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
                        <mat-label class="text-center" >Por defecto: 1.4 s</mat-label>
                        <input matInput class="big-input" placeholder="Por defecto: 1.4 s">
                      </mat-form-field>
                    </p>
                  </td>
                  <td class="row-middle">
                    <p class="input input-password mb-1">
                      <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
                        <mat-label>Por defecto: 1.4 s</mat-label>
                        <input matInput class="big-input" placeholder="Por defecto: 1.4 s">
                      </mat-form-field>
                    </p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para alinear veritcalmente los elementos te bastaría con la propiedad **vertical-align** de **css** en posición **middle**, aplicada sobre la clase que te interesa. Lo ideal sería crear una exprofeso para no alterar las del framework con que trabajas.

```css
td {padding:20px; background-color: yellow;}

td.row-left-border.table-firmware-name{vertical-algin:middle;}
```

```html
<table matSort class="table table-lg mt-3 main-table big-cells" aria-describedby="mydesc">
                <thead class="col-lg-6">
                  <tr>
                    <th class="table-margin"></th>
                    <th mat-sort-header="name" class="table-firmware-name">Parametros</th>
                    <th mat-sort-header="version" class="table-small-col">Umbral de Proteccion</th>
                    <th mat-sort-header="device_model" class="table-medium-col">Tiempo de Actuacion</th>
                    <th class="table-margin"></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                  <tbody class="section-list pb-lg-3 mb-lg-5 mx-lg-3">
                    <tr  class="generic-card px-lg-4 py-lg-3 mb-lg-2">
                      <td></td>
                      <td class="row-left-border table-firmware-name">SobreTension - Fase 1</td>
                      <td class="row-middle">
                        <p class="input input-password mb-1">
                          <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
                            <mat-label class="text-center" >Por defecto: 1.4 s</mat-label>
                            <input matInput class="big-input" placeholder="Por defecto: 1.4 s">
                          </mat-form-field>
                        </p>
                      </td>
                      <td class="row-middle">
                        <p class="input input-password mb-1">
                          <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
                            <mat-label>Por defecto: 1.4 s</mat-label>
                            <input matInput class="big-input" placeholder="Por defecto: 1.4 s">
                          </mat-form-field>
                        </p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
```

Si quieres hacerlo con **flex** en este caso se aplicaría del siguiente modo:

```css
td.row-left-border{ padding:20px; background-color: red; display: flex;align-items:  center;justify-content: center;}
```

```html
<table matSort class="table table-lg mt-3 main-table big-cells" aria-describedby="mydesc">
                <thead class="col-lg-6">
                  <tr>
                    <th class="table-margin"></th>
                    <th mat-sort-header="name" class="table-firmware-name">Parametros</th>
                    <th mat-sort-header="version" class="table-small-col">Umbral de Proteccion</th>
                    <th mat-sort-header="device_model" class="table-medium-col">Tiempo de Actuacion</th>
                    <th class="table-margin"></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                  <tbody class="section-list pb-lg-3 mb-lg-5 mx-lg-3">
                    <tr  class="generic-card px-lg-4 py-lg-3 mb-lg-2">
                      <td></td>
                      <td class="row-left-border table-firmware-name">SobreTension - Fase 1</td>
                      <td class="row-middle">
                        <p class="input input-password mb-1">
                          <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
                            <mat-label class="text-center" >Por defecto: 1.4 s</mat-label>
                            <input matInput class="big-input" placeholder="Por defecto: 1.4 s">
                          </mat-form-field>
                        </p>
                      </td>
                      <td class="row-middle">
                        <p class="input input-password mb-1">
                          <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
                            <mat-label>Por defecto: 1.4 s</mat-label>
                            <input matInput class="big-input" placeholder="Por defecto: 1.4 s">
                          </mat-form-field>
                        </p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
```